# JSF 3.0 - jakarta.el.ELException: Property not found on type

Tags: jsf

Any ideas why this sample project fails to find the backing bean property? Thank you in advance.

This is a sample project just to test Jakarta namespaces. When attempting to view hello.xhtml, method submit() on Hello.java is not found with the stack trace:

```
jakarta.el.ELException: /hello.xhtml: Property [submit] not found on type [jakarta.tutorial.web.faces.Hello$$OwbNormalScopeProxy0]
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.AttributeInstruction.write(AttributeInstruction.java:55)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:46)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:491)
at jakarta.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:554)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1897)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:315)
at jakarta.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:73)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:122)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:266)
at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:67)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
at io.smallrye.metrics.jaxrs.JaxRsMetricsServletFilter.doFilter(JaxRsMetricsServletFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:356)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:870)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1762)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

There is a Hello.java @RequestScoped bean in package jakarta.tutorial.web.faces with a hello.xhtml file in web root directory 'webapp'.

Directory structure:

```
src/main/java -
              - jakarta
                 - tutorial
                  - web
                   - faces
                    - Hello.java
              - webapp
                 - hello.xhtml
                 - WEB-INF
                   - beans.xml
                   - web.xml
```

Hello.java

```
package jakarta.tutorial.web.faces;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Hello
{
    private String name;
    private String greeting;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        greeting = "Presubmit greeting";
    }
    
    public void submit() {
        greeting = "Hello, " + name + "!";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGreeting() {
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

hello.xtml

```
<html lang="en"
  xmlns:f="jakarta.faces.core"
  xmlns:h="jakarta.faces.html">
<h:head>
    <title>Jakarta Faces Hello World</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Hello, what's your name?</h1>
    
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{hello.name}" required="true" />
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{hello.submit}">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":greeting" />
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:messages />
    </h:form>
    <h:outputText id="greeting" value="#{hello.greeting}" />
</h:body>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Test-Jakarta</groupId>
  <artifactId>Test-Jakarta</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>   
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>20</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                 xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" 
                 xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd" 
                 version="5.0">
          <display-name>Test-Jakarta</display-name>
          <servlet>
            <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
          </servlet>
          <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>
        
          <context-param>
            <param-name>jakarta.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
            <param-value>Development</param-value>
          </context-param> 
          <context-param>
            <description>
                State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 
            </description>
            <param-name>jakarta.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
            <param-value>client</param-value>
          </context-param>
          <context-param>
            <param-name>jakarta.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
          </context-param>
          <context-param>
            <param-name>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
            <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
          </context-param>
          <context-param>
            <param-name>jakarta.faces.ENABLE_WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
          </context-param>
          <context-param>
            <param-name>jakarta.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY</param-name>
            <param-value>/resources</param-value>
          </context-param>  
          
</web-app>
```

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/beans_3_0.xsd"
       version="3.0" bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

I've alternately tried specifying org.apache.myfaces.core in pom.xml with the same result

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Settings file org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <fixed facet="jst.web"/>
  <fixed facet="java"/>
  <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
  <installed facet="jst.jsf" version="3.0"/>
  <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="5.0"/>
  <installed facet="java" version="19"/>
</faceted-project>
```